# MongoDB throws delete message "DELETED_BECAUSE_YOU_DIDNT_PASSWORD_PROTECT_YOUR_MONGODB"

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.0.4 version, i am login to shell command in mongodb
working is fine. but now mongodb is deleted automatically. i am using this command

```
> mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: test
> show dbs
DELETED_BECAUSE_YOU_DIDNT_PASSWORD_PROTECT_YOUR_MONGODB 0.203125GB
admin   0.203125GB
local   (empty)
>
```

I don't know database deleted or not but showing database list and size.
how to get backup my database please help me.

Comment: And it's not even April 1st. Hint, if you spoke to your colleages about this they are all having a laugh together.

Comment: I'll relieve @Elango Read the line. Then do it again, and again. There is something which is quite unusual for an exception...

Comment: And for God's sake, update your MongoDB...

Comment: That's not an error message - it's the name of a/the-only database. Also, sadly, the expected consequence of [mongodb being insecure by default](https://blog.shodan.io/its-the-data-stupid/) for a loooong time.

Answer (score 7):

It appears like you exposed your MongoDB database to the public internet without password protection. Someone noticed it and decided to teach you a lesson by deleting your database.

People running MongoDB in production without authentication [is unfortunately a common problem](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/07/21/drongo_mongodbs_spew_600_terabytes_of_unauthenticated_data/), because up to version 2.4.14 this was the factory default configuration. You appear to be using the very outdated 2.0.4, so this is very likely also the case for you. The idea was that people were supposed to run MongoDB in a protected backend with the application in the DMZ, but not many people were aware of this (including many SaaS providers which rent out unsecured MongoDB instances).

For more information about how to set up MongoDB securely, consult [the MongoDB security guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/MongoDB-security-guide.pdf).

Regarding your second question *"how to get backup my database"*: Do you *have* a backup? MongoDB doesn't do automatic backups unless you set this up yourself. When you don't know if you have a backup, you likely don't. So I'm really sorry, but unfortunately you are screwed.

Comment: They also appears to be running on their local machine ( no connection string in the question ). So rather than a "serious" issue of how to enfore security, this is very likely a "prank" by a co-worker trying to enforce the same lesson.

Comment: @BlakesSeven why would you conclude this is a prank by a co-worker? In what way is it not a serious issue that mongodb listened on 0.0.0.0 by default and "[A quick search for MongoDB reveals that there are nearly 30,000 instances on the Internet that don't have any authorization enabled](https://blog.shodan.io/its-the-data-stupid/)"?

Comment: @AD7six You're all taking this way to seriously. Two people talking about instances running on their own machines, and the data should be junk anyway. Mine is. Of course "production" systems need protection, 100% aggree there. Bu I don't think we're talking fortune 500 or even $5 on the 30,000 either. Nor that because someone "blogged" it it's true. Why a prank? If it looks like a duck....

Comment: Well, you could be right @BlakesSeven though there's no indication they are running on their local machines (if there is - what is this indicator). Alternatively a known published exploit has been exploited; and "exploit" is connecting to the remote database and running commands - it's not like it's even remotely difficult to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is unfortunately not a prank like someone suggested. Today the same thing happened to us. On a test server that we didn't secure yet all our mongodb databases were deleted and replaced with the exact same database: DELETED_BECAUSE_YOU_DIDNT_PASSWORD_PROTECT_YOUR_MONGODB

Fortunately all the data there was junk but double check your server security if you have something important.

EDIT

The attack was from 89.248.167.159

It's a bot doing this so be aware.

Inside the "DELETED_BECAUSE_...." database there is a collection named users and inside that collection a single document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55b4d4d486588b0a4703eb0f"), "username" : "byterot" }
```